# how many cores can i assign to my vmware virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware

I have an i5 8th gen intel CPU on my laptop. I have to do a lot of switching from Windows to Linux and I certainly don't want a dual boot so my question is what is the max limit of cores can I assign to my Xubuntu virtual machine. I want max performance in my virtual machine I have 20Gb ram and a 512GB SSD with 2GB MX230 graphic card. currently, I have assigned 4cores to my VM and 8GB of ram

Comment: Have a look at my answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1602681/what-are-the-limits-of-allocating-my-cpu-cores-to-vms/1602686#1602686

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the limits of allocating my CPU cores to VMs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1602681/what-are-the-limits-of-allocating-my-cpu-cores-to-vms)

Comment: The linked question is about running multiple simultaneous VMs. Different rules apply, especially whether the backgrounded VMs are allowed to sleep or change priority.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule of thumb for core allocation is simply "your **real** core count" excluding HT cores.

This lets each side of the equation have best access to available cores & if running the VM at full capacity still allows the host machine to breathe.
This has been my long-tested way to run app compiles or video compression - tasks that will eat all available resources - even if I'm running identical OSes inside & outside the VM.